# How to create a jquery loader when page is loaded or opened?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello guys just want to ask how can I create an Ajax loader when my page is load? For example after I logged in to my page there will be a modal loader that will display a loader picture. How can I do that? Here's my sample code:

**Im using jpreloader**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/resources/jquery.jpreloader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        /* FOR LOADER */
        $('body').jpreloader();
    });

</script>
<body>
     <!-- THE REST HERE -->
</body>
```

Comment: are you sure you did the proper call from header ? you can verify that first. @user2585508 here is our original jpreLoader code from our project: http://maquetas.fen.uchile.cl/sitio_oficial_portal/js/jpreLoader.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at jpreloader, it's the plugin we use for our university faculty website: [jpreloader.js](https://gist.github.com/GamePlayern/5384529)

It's very easy to use and implement, just add this to your javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').jpreLoader();
});
```

Comment: Hello i downloded the javascript and included in my code my it is not working.

Comment: @user2585508 here is our original code http://maquetas.fen.uchile.cl/sitio_oficial_portal/js/jpreLoader.js include it in the header of HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can find many libs that will do it for you, check this nice ones:

- http://monkeymonk.be/jquery.loader.js/demo/
- http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/ (I liked it)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that we have the same problem before, this is my question and I hope it helps to you, [How to determine if the `.post` request has been started and finish in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719289/how-to-determine-if-the-post-request-has-been-started-and-finish-in-jquery)

But if ever this will not satisfy the problem, I think it depends on how the design of your login module, paste some code so that we could know how you design it.